# Spatial / geographical modeling

Tags: regression, spatial, generalized-additive-model

Normally when I try to model spatial risk, I include it in my mgcv::gam model using a two-dimensional spline. Do you guys know of any other statistical methods that could be interesting for me to take a look at?

I'm thinking about an approach of not including a two-dimensional spline in my gam, but rather taking the logarithm of the residuals and modeling the geographical/spatial effect afterwards.

To give context to my question, as to the points of @whuber:

- I am modelling a lot of different things, but normally my data are count data which I model using binomial regression or poisson regression. The counts are measured repeatedly over time, but I treat my measures as independent. I normally have many explanatory variables in addition to the geographical coordinates.
- There is definitely spatial correlation present
- The spacial support of the data the following (I guess): every data point has a longitude and lattitude. These coordinates represent the **centers** of polygonal regions. Normally these regions are counties within a country, regions which have the same postal code etc. So the number of regions might vary from 1000 to 5000 to 10000, it depends.
- Objectives: create the best predictive model I can. One employer I had some time ago, wanted to see if we could see which regions that were high risk of customers defaulting their loan, so I used a gam with a two-dimensional spline, trying to predict risk of default. Another time I was measuring fish deaths (count data) of some fixed regions on sea, modelling this with Poisson regression, and trying to predict the mean of number of dead fish.

Comment: I have (literally) an entire shelf of books answering your question, because there is such a wide variety of spatial models. Your problem can be narrowed in various natural ways, including by describing what kind of data you have, what you assume or know about the nature of spatial correlation, how extensive the spatial support of the data is, and the objectives of your modeling exercise.

Comment: thank you @whuber! I just added some text to try to answer your points

Comment: That's a beginning.  But what do those coordinates represent: actual point locations or--since the data are counts--would they just be centers of polygonal regions? Are the counts measured repeatedly over time or can they be measured only once? What exactly do you need to predict (another count, an average, something else)? How were the data locations selected: are they natural, fixed locations, a random sample, or some kind of guided sample like observations along a transect? How far across the Earth do the locations extend? How many locations are there?  *Etc.*

Comment: thanks again @whuber: now it should be more clear!

Comment: I think it will be necessary to ask a specific question about a specific problem before we can attempt an answer here on CV, because this is still a huge open-ended situation.  You might want to begin exploring some of the literature on [spatial analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_analysis).

Comment: @whuber Yes, all I want are some possible techniques that *could* be useful for me to take a look at, as you said, you have a bookshelf of books in this subject, but somebody must surely have some *idea* of methods that *could* be useful for me. Sorry, I just don't see why this is not a useful question to get some broad pointers on, surely there must be people that are in my position that could benefit from this as well =)

Comment: @whuber: is it really that important to close this question, just because it is broad? I mean, what is the harm of getting some pointers to different techniques I could use?